# Dynamic Bag of Words / Features

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to implement a Bag of Features for a set of images submitted in different moments by a set of users.

If the clusters change, then we need to recompute at LEAST all the "visual words" which elements has changed cluster.

For example, suppose that one SIFT descriptor `d` at time `t1` belongs to cluster `A`. At `t1+1` a query is submitted, and so the clusters change and now `d` belongs to cluster `B`. So we need to re-compute the "visual word" (vector) relative to `d`.

As you can imagine, this approach can be too much expensive (especially if query rate is high)!

**My question is**: there is a better model than the classic bag of words, or some dynamic clustering algorithm?

Comment: Please **don't double-post**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215219/7828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on your other question, it is assumed the **visual words were trained on a complete (diverse and large) enough data set**.

If every interesting key point has a good enough visual word, then you don't need to update the visual words, only map new images to the existing vocabulary.

Even if you assume your data changes constantly, there is no use in updating the vocabulary all the time. It's a rough approximation - after recomputing it still remains only a rough approximation. It's enough to update if you have received a *substantial* amount of new data. Updating more often than that will likely yield 0.0 improvement at a massive cost.